# How to find a complete path to an icon from the hosting template?

Tags: html, css, path, icons

I'm using some template from the hosting shoptet.cz .
They are using phone, email icons etc but in CSS is only:

```
#header-in .header-email a:before {
content: "\e601";
}
```

How do I get a path to these icons? I want to use some of them in different places on the website. But when I insert the same content code it's just square.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you are confused about the way icon fonts work. Simply Google: How to use icon fonts and you will surely find an answer.

Comment: Hmm, I found how to insert some new icons but still don't know what font they used and how to use icons from their font which is already on the website. Do you have any forum where I can ask for a guide? I just need to put there one icon... I just get minus here...

Comment: You can find out by inspecting this specific element and checking for the font-family it is using. https://www.browserstack.com/guide/inspect-element-in-chrome

Comment: @prettyInPink It's shoptet font-family

Comment: They likely created a custom font using some generator, like IcoMoon: https://icomoon.io/app/#/select

Comment: If you are loading correctly this font family (no errors in console), you can use the classes provided in the stylesheet (such as: ```.shoptet-icon-mail```), and don't need to specify it in css. If however you can't add this class in html and need to specify it to ```#header-in .header-email a```, you will need to specify it is you did, but make sure to include the font-family name as well as the correct font weight, in this case being: ```font-family: 'shoptet';``` and ```font-weight: normal;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, prettyInPink. I just inserted another span with the class that I have found in that file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).